# how do I query total available CPU cores on a spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark

Using Spark, I have a complex job, one phase of which is CPU intensive, single-thread and easily fits into memory.  I can partition the data into tasks but it must be done manually.  Being CPU limited, the optimal number of tasks will be equal to the total CPU cores on the cluster.  My questions:

- How do I know the total number of CPU cores available for execution?
- I've read that executors might be multi-core "fat", will the concurrency of my single-thread tasks be limited to the number of executors?